# Flutter keyboard not showing up on both emulator and real devices>

Tags: flutter, keyboard, dart-null-safety, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, flutter2.0

**What I mean is that the keyboard did show up for milliseconds and it then disappeared immediately, this is inside a Modal Bottom Sheet, but I don't think it's the problem of the Sheet.**

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: double.infinity,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: kAccent,
    border: Border(
      top: BorderSide(color: kBackground, width: 0.5),
    ),
  ),
  child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        width: hasText ? 300 : 350,
        height: 40,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: kPrimary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: _komNode,
          controller: _kommentCtrl,
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: 'Leave seme nice K-omments~',
            hintStyle: kOnPrimaryMediumText,
          ),
          maxLength: 100,
        ),
      ),
);
```

I saw some people says this is the bug of compile version 28, and it can be fix if you downgrade it to 27, but my project is Sound Null Safety already, and if I do the downgrade, I have to rewrite the whole app, thus, I can't downgrade it to 27.

**Can anybody help me to fix this issue? @_@**

Comment: Are you sure its not caused by the TextField's focusNode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a key to the `TextField`,

```
child: TextField(
          key: ValueKey("Your unique value"),  
          focusNode: _komNode,
          controller: _kommentCtrl,
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: 'Leave seme nice K-omments~',
            hintStyle: kOnPrimaryMediumText,
          ),
          maxLength: 100,
        ),
```

### Update

I think the problem is that the text field loses focus when you open the modal sheet and thus the keyboard closes, so try and declare your widget outside your build method first. like this:

```
final _myModalSheet =  Container(
  //...
  child: Container(
        //...
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: _komNode,
          controller: _kommentCtrl,
          //...
          ),
        ),
      ),
);
```

and then add _myModalSheet in your build method.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me~ @_@

Comment: THANK YO SO MUCH! IT IS SOLVED! This is my first time that post a issue on Stack Overflow by the way~ @_@

Comment: Happy to help :D did the content disappearing problem got fixed ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed that by my-self, thank you again! @_@